# Returning aggregations from HBASE data

Tags: nosql, hadoop, hbase

I have an HBASE table of about 150k rows, each containing 3700 columns.

I need to select multiple rows at a time, and aggregate the results back, something like:

row[1][column1] + row[2][column1] ... + row[n][column1]
row[1][column2] + row[2][column2] ... + row[n][column2]
...
row[1][columnn] + row[2][columnn] ... + row[n][columnn]

Which I can do using a scanner, the issue is, I believe, that the scanner is like a cursor, and is not doing the work distributed over multiple machines at the same time, but rather getting data from one region, then hopping to another region to get the next set of data, and so on where my results span multiple regions.

Is there a way to scan in a distributed fashion (an option, or creating multiple scanners for each region's worth of data [This might be a can of worms in itself]) or is this something that must be done in a map/reduce job. If it's a M/R job, will it be "fast" enough for real time queries? If not, are there some good alternatives to doing these types of aggregations in realtime with a NOSQL type database?

Answer (score 2):

What I would do in such cases is, have another table where I would have the aggregation summaries. That is When row[m] is inserted into table 1 in table 2 against (column 1) (which is the row key of table 2) I would save its summation or other aggregational results, be it average, standard deviation, max, min etc.

Another approach would be to index them into a search tool such as Lucene, Solr, Elastic Search etc. and run aggregational searches there. Here are some examples in [Solr](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery).

Finally, Scan spanning across multiple region or M/R jobs is not designed for real time queries (unless the clusters designed in such way, i.e. oversized to data requirements).

Hope it helps.